# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails at Pentaho data Integration

Tags: pentaho

i want to add row of data to my database which is that row of data is a foreign key at other table, but when i run this ETL, i'm still get this error like this
[image]

So, i wanna know where the problem is and solution to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite self-explanatory:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ('madina', 'fakta_rajal', CONSTRAINT 'fakta_rajal_ibfk_7' FOREIGN KEY ('sk_pasien') REFERENCES 'dms_pasien' ('sk_pasien')
```

That means you are inserting in a table referencing the table **dms_pasien** with a foreign key named **fakta_rajal_ibfk_7** referencing the column **sk_pasien** in the table **dms_pasien**. The value you are trying to insert in your table doesn't exist in **dms_pasien**, you'll have to check your data to ensure that value exists.

Comment: I have checked the data values in dms_pasien table, data type and data length between them and it's same and exist. I don't know why i still get that error.

Comment: In these cases it's usually a space character or new line that plays havoc. You can activate the debug mode to debug line by line to detect which of your entry values is giving this error.

Comment: You could also add the treatment of errors, so instead of stopping the transformation, you copy the error rows to a file and only insert the correct ones.

Comment: Thank you so much, so how to do it then? i'm sorry, i'm newbie, didn't know that much about pentaho well